# 'Whose' in this CAE transformation

Tags: grammar

I am doing CAE Transformations and I came across the following transformation.
The answer (according to the answer key) is: ***"no idea whose folder it was"***

1. Why can't " no idea whose the folder was" work here?
2. Are there other transformations you can suggest?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

> She had no idea whose folder it was

is fine.

> She had no idea whose the folder was

is also fine, since you're just swapping "whose" as a *determiner/adjective* with "whose" as a *pronoun*.  Similar example using *which*:

> She couldn't remember **which** was the house Mary lived in.
>
> She couldn't remember **which** house Mary lived in (*or* in which house Mary lived).

Although good English style would probably say the second is better than the first, sometimes structures like "which was the house" *sound* better to enhance the feeling of confusion, by emphasizing *which* over *house*.

As a side note, I've tried a few CAE questions, and they can be quite difficult. Some ask me to use structures I would not naturally write (possibly because they are more common in UK English).  Also, in some cases the question required me to change the main verb, which means there could be more than one possible answer.